# Dealing with cross-site duplicates

Tags: discussion, questions

[This question](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/6103/forced-doing-what-i-think-is-misleading) is a duplicate of [SO's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336689/forced-doing-what-i-think-is-misleading) which OP even directly states (otherwise I wouldn't even notice). Anyway my question would be what is the standard way of dealing with such cases?

Ideally we'd like to have only one question across the sites. Should we advise OP to delete the question on other site or migrate and merge it here?

Answer (score 1):

Cross posting of questions between sites is discouraged since it creates noise and spreads answers across the different sites. If the question were on topic on PMSE, you could leave a comment asking the asker to delete the other question. You could also flag it on the other site for removal.

I went ahead and flagged it on Stack Overflow for removal. Thanks for pointing this out.

I feel like this question is -- at the very least -- off topic for PMSE as it doesn't appear to be about project management. Also, the "design A" and "design B" abstractions make it hard to definitively answer this question since we have no context to decide which coworker the asker describes is right or wrong, and I don't see it helping future visitors. Based on this lack of detail and the nature of the topic, we could close this question as not constructive, not a real question, or off-topic.

Since our site scope is in a state of change, I must ask, what do you think about this question?

Comment: For me the question is within the site's scope, maybe on scope's border. Yes, the context here is software design, but the problem is about a project decision or, looking deeper, about project organization. How much freedom people have to make own decisions, what are consequences of breaking rules, etc. At the same it goes a bit beyond scope with the part of the discussion on further career (which isn't PM career). All in all I'm OK to see this question on PMSE.

Comment: @PawelBrodzinski - I removed the word "strongly" from my original answer. I realize that particular adjective is one I should instead reserve for questions like this: http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/6108/what-is-a-good-dead-simple-project-management-tool.

Comment: I flagged the question as not constructive because it's too subjective. However, too localized and off-topic are good choices, too. http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/6103/forced-to-implement-what-i-think-is-the-wrong-solution#comment5376_6103

Comment: @CodeGnome - Thanks for the flagging help. I'm not 100% sure if I'm going to take action on it yet, but your flag, and any other flags/close votes is definitely something that we'll consider when making this decision.

Answer (score 1):

This question is helpful in defining what is on-topic.

Should we accept questions about project managers or questions which solicit the opinions of project managers (so the team member who works with a pm gets a better perspective)?

In that light, I'd say it is off-topic since it is subjective/soliciting opinions rather than looking for a "practical, answerable questions."

btw, this seems to be what the asker of [How to Adapt to a New Team Culture?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/6111/how-to-adapt-to-a-new-team-culture) was going for and why they came to the site looking for an answer. With that in mind, it would be off-topic for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

#### Close or Delete, Don't Migrate

In this specific instance, I believe the correct solution is to either close or delete it. We shouldn't migrate poor-quality or off-topic questions, and I can't think of any site other than Programmers where this would be even vaguely on-topic. Even if it's on-topic, I think it's either too localized or too subjective to be appropriate for migration.

#### Why Close Seems Better

Personally, I'd probably close it, since it has a highly-upvoted answer that would be lost if it were deleted. I think that's definitely a judgment call, though.

Comment: +1 - It's Stack Exchange policy that only really outstanding questions should be migrated, and only in cases where the question really is off-topic for the source site. In most cases, off-topic questions should simply be closed (or deleted) :).